# Exceptions (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, custom-exceptions

Ok I have been trying this exercise because I am not good at exceptions.So here is the context of the exercise:Write a class with main method(the following code is give by the task):

```
public class task{

public static void main(
String[] args)
{
int[] array = new int[10];
// initialise array
int result =task.min(array); 
// Where the class task
// contains the min method
}
```

so I am asked to make  sure that the method works
even if the array contains only one element or none at all.So with the code give above I have to use exceptions to handle all the errors that could pop up.

This is what I did:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
int[] array = new int[10];
        array[0]=5;
        array[1]=7;

        int result =Exercise1.min(array); 
        if(array.length<=0){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("empty array");
        }
        else if(array.length<10 && array.length>0){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("I got just these numbers");
        }
            System.out.println(result);


            }
    public static int min(int[] array) {
        int min = array[0]; 
          for(int i=1;i<array.length;i++){  
                 if(array[i]< min){  
                 min = array[i];  
                    }  
          }
        return min;
    }
}
```

However no matter what I write the output is always 0 and I don't understand why.In case my approach is entirely wrong please offer some advice.

Comment: Your exceptions should be inside `min` method and you have to handle them in `main` method. Apart of that, your code should work as expected. Probably you have problems executing the code and you get the result of the last valid execution, where it printed 0.

Comment: `if(array[i]< min){min = array[i]; }` this makes min always get set to the lowest value, since `array[2-9] = 0`, min returns 0

Comment: your array will always have length 10 if it's declared as int[10]. it doesn't resize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`int[] array = new int[10];`

This line of code sets 10 places of the `array` "array", all equal to "0".

In order for `min` to not return 0 you need to set all the values of the array or change the size to 2.

Setting them could easily be done with this function:

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    array[i] = i + 1;
}
```

This will set all the values of the array so you can remove this code:

```
array[0]=5;
array[1]=7;
```

Setting these will fix your min value always being 0.

It will always be 1 if you use my suggested loop.

Answer (score 1):

When you create an array of int they are all set to zero, hence that is the minimum value in your array.

Answer (score 1):

If you can change your input:

```
ArrayList<Integer> array = new ArrayList<Integer>();
array.add(5);
[...]
```

Or you can change your condition, assuming YOU CAN'T HAVE the 0 value in your array.

```
for(int i=1;i<array.length && array[i]!=0;i++){  
  if(array[i]< min){  
    min = array[i];  
  }  
}
```

This will solve your current problem so you can focus on your Exception practise